# UV-absorption capability of air

Tags: resource-recommendations, laser, air, absorption, data

I am looking for an absorption chart for UV light with a wavelength of around 250 nm in air (ambient, no specific preparation). How much of a beam of this light would be absorbed per meter of path length? I am aware that this depends on the specific conditions but for now an approximate value would be sufficient. I could not find any scientific works on that (in a brief search).

Comment: You could estimate this fairly easily this with an uncalibrated UV photodiode +transimpedance amp and UVC LED. Measure output at some distance then change the distance and compare the output. Just don't forget to compensate for the inverse square law since they are not lasers. Also LED illumination patterns are not even.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually kind of difficult to make good measurements in that spectral range, although with better UV sources it should be getting better. You can try to build up the [absorption spectra from a database like HITRAN](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0022-4073(03)00173-0) that has absorption cross section data but that may be of limited usefulness since real air is more complicated. There is also scientific debate about UV [absorption by water vapor](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1134/S1024856013010119.pdf), for practical applications like gas spectroscopy in meter long optical cells people will take multiple baselines and average them, but don't necessarily publish the baseline data.

The for real air, you have the issues of particulate and water vapor and the the scattering also depends on how the water vapor interacts with the aerosols.

Edit: I guess I should add that the other problem is at 250 nm the absorption is small which also makes it hard to measure accuratly.